# Смена изображений в слайдере

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Всем привет, есть такой слайдер, который меняет изображения, но проблема в том, что меняет он их некорректно. То есть он  добавляет еще 1 изображения,а уже потом убирает второе.

http://prntscr.com/mmke1u

Можете ли вы подсказать, как правильно организовать плавную смену?

```js
$('.tab-block .tabs .item').eq(0).addClass('active');
$('.tab-block .tab-content .item').eq(0).show();
let tabsH = $('.tab-block .tabs').height();
$('.tab-block .tab-content').css('min-height', tabsH);

$('.tab-block .tabs .item').on('click', function() {
  let i = $(this).index(),
    parent = $(this).closest('.tab-block');
  parent.find('.tabs .item.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  parent.find('.tab-content .item').fadeOut(700).eq(i).fadeIn(700);
});
```

```css
.tab-block {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 20px/26px HelveticaNeueCyr;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  color: #333
}

.tab-block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}

.tab-block .tabs,
.tab-block .tab-content {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.tab-block .tabs {
  border-left: 2px solid #fff
}

.tab-block .tabs .item:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tab-block .tabs .item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tab-block .tabs .item.active {
  border-left: 2px solid #0c569b;
  color: #0c569b;
  margin-left: -2px
}

.tab-block .tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right
}

.tab-block .tab-content .item:not(.active) {
  display: none
}

.tab-content .item img {
  max-width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-block">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="item">Регистрационные данные</div>
    <div class="item">Индексы благонадёжности</div>
    <div class="item">Арбитражная практика</div>
    <div class="item">Аффилированность котрагентов</div>
    <div class="item">Реестр жалоб в ФАС</div>
    <div class="item">Реестр недобросовестных поставщиков</div>
    <div class="item">Банковские гарантии</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/877x500p/s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/contentlab.studiod/getty/f24b4a7bf9f24d1ba5f899339e6949f3" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://clck.ru/ETfTF" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S как сделать автоподгон изображений в слйдере?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо в атрибутах `tabs > item` добавлять ссылку на фото, после чего нажимаете на Элемент, изменялся `src= tab-content` (а не класс уже существующих элементов)

```js
$('.tab-block .tabs .item').on('click', function() {
  var img_src = $(this).attr('img_src');
  $('.tab-content .item').attr('src', img_src);
});
```

```css
.tab-content .item {
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-block">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="item" img_src="https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/877x500p/s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/contentlab.studiod/getty/f24b4a7bf9f24d1ba5f899339e6949f3" alt="">Регистрационные данные</div>
    <div class="item" img_src="https://clck.ru/ETfTF">Индексы благонадёжности</div>
    <div class="item" img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg">Арбитражная практика</div>
    <div class="item" img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg">Аффилированность котрагентов</div>
    <div class="item" img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg">Реестр жалоб в ФАС</div>
    <div class="item" img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg">Реестр недобросовестных поставщиков</div>
    <div class="item" img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg">Банковские гарантии</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: то есть вместо этой части написать ваш блок?
 let i = $(this).index(),
    parent = $(this).closest('.tab-block');
  parent.find('.tabs .item.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

просто я хочу ,чтобы элемент некоторый был еще и активен

Comment: вы можете им присваивать любые классы которые хотите, главное чтобы классы не имели свойств  по "display", то есть чтобы не скрывали или наоборот показывали данный блок где должно быть главная фотография.